# combining two string variables

Tags: python

I'm a novice Python user trying to do something that I think should be simple but can't figure it out.  I've got 2 variables defined:

```
a = 'lemon'
b = 'lime'
```

Can someone tell me how to combine these in a new variable?

If I try:

```
>>> soda = "a" + "b"
>>> soda
'ab'
```

I want soda to be `'lemonlime'`. How is this done?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good novice question -- you satisfied all the guidelines: show what you're trying to accomplish, show what you've tried, ask a specific question. +1 BTW, the terminology for "combining" two strings in this manner is "concatenation" (which is derived from Latin for "chain" as in "chain together").

Comment: @Jim Garrison speaks the truth. Keep asking questions in this manner and you'll keep getting solid answers.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

you need to take out the quotes:

```
soda = a + b
```

(You want to refer to the *variables* `a` and `b`, not the *strings* "a" and "b")

Comment: Thanks froadie!  Way too simple...much appreciated!

Answer (score 21):

IMO, froadie's simple concatenation is fine for a simple case like you presented.  If you want to put together several strings, the [string join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method seems to be preferred:

```
the_text = ''.join(['the ', 'quick ', 'brown ', 'fox ', 'jumped ', 'over ', 'the ', 'lazy ', 'dog.'])
```

Edit:  Note that join wants an iterable (e.g. a list) as its single argument.

Comment: An excellent point, Matt - I'll remember that as well!

Comment: Since a string is also an iterable, you can join on a string as well: `' '.join('Eric')` => `'E r i c'`