# I need to find a way to merge 2 strings in python in a certain order?

Tags: python, string

```
String1 = "abcd"
String2 = "uvwxyz"
```

I want it to merge to look like this: `aubvcwdxyz`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [combining two string variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205532/combining-two-string-variables)

Comment: @KaveenPerera That's not at all relevant.

Comment: @Tagc Sorry mate just noticed the difference on the re edited post.

Comment: What python version do you want to use?

Comment: you could use `itertools.zip_longest(String1, String2)` and later concatenate elements - but it can be too high level for homework.

Comment: @furas You posted this comment exactly one second before my answer. :)

Comment: @Tagc yes :) I clicked "Add Comment" and then it shows me your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

s1 = "abcd"
s2 = "uvwxyz"
s3 = ''.join(a + b for a, b in zip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue=''))
print(s3)
```

**Output**

```
aubvcwdxyz
```

---

Here's a version that works with Python 2. Spot the difference!

```
from itertools import izip_longest

s1 = "abcd"
s2 = "uvwxyz"
s3 = ''.join(a + b for a, b in izip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue=''))
print(s3)
```

Comment: Reminder: works only in python 3 (just posted python 2 version)

Comment: @MaLiN2223 I wish we'd just let Python 2 die but I included the Python 2 version all the same.

Comment: @Tagc you are not alone however there are too much soft written in 'old' python. You can merge your answer by using : if sys.version_info[0] >= 3 :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use python 2:

```
a = list("abcd")
b = list("uvwxyz")
q = list(map(None, a, b))
output = ""
for i in q:
    if i[0] is not None:
        output+=i[0]
    if i[1] is not None:
        output+=i[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [`iteration_utilities.roundrobin`](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/roundrobin.html):

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import roundrobin

>>> ''.join(roundrobin(String1, String2))
'aubvcwdxyz'
```

---

<sup>1 This is from a third-party library I have written: [`iteration_utilities`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/iteration_utilities).</sup>